# Capturing from where the page was accessed in Site Catalyst

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have certain pages in my application which can be accessed from different locations. For example, let's say "`Page A`" can be accessed from links in the site header as well as from the links in site Footer. What is the right way to capture this
information in Site Catalyst? is something like "`siteID:header:PageA`" & "`siteID:footer:PageA`" OR use some additional `sProp` to tell that it was from "header" or "footer"
I'm not looking for the referrer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should use [Adobe Analytics Activity Map](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/analytics/activitymap/activitymap-enable.html) for this. If you are keeping up with the latest Adobe Analytics libraries, you probably already have this implemented and just need to enable the Activity Map reports in the AA interface (and install the browser extension if you want to be able to go to a page and see data for links on the page itself).

Comment: We are using v27.5 of s_code.js file? Will that version be sufficient?

Comment: @Apps v27.5 is legacy H library version. From the link I provided, you need to be on the AppMeasurement library, minimum v1.6 (current version is v2.5). My advice to you is since you are still on legacy H lib version, your highest priority should be migration to AppMeasurement library.